# Display categories with styling

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am building my own Wordpress theme for a client. I want to display the categories, but with some styling.

This is a screenshot of what I would like to achieve using categories:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOs4f.jpg (In these screenshots "Behang" and "Wanddecoraties" are categories being displayed.)

I already created categories within Wordpress and made category.php. It works when I use  wp_list_categories( $args );  to display a list of categories. But I can't figure out how to add styling and HTML to each category (also a thumbnail).

Thank you for your help!

Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a *get_categories( $args )* function. The function returns an array of categories specifed by passed parameters. After assigned it to the variable you can iterate over items:

```
$categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category){
    echo $category->name;
}
```

Look at the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) to learn more.